# 3ds max 2012 additional face data

Tags: 3dsmax

I need to export a terrain mesh from my 3ds scene to a text format so that I can read it into my game. I would like some additional data about the faces of the triangles exported as well such as what surface type ( concrete, grass, dirt ) they represent. Is there a way of assigning additional data about faces in 3ds max and then a way to export to a text file that I can read.

Answer (score 0):

For a custom human-readable file, you can use the MAXScript language – there are many exporter scripts to look at and/or modify (search google for MAXScript csv export, for example) and a [set of chapters](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/14/ENU/MAXScript%20Help%202012/files/GUID-83DB7484-5C65-4043-ADFF-2D4100DADD5-321.htm) in the MAXScript reference. The surface type you are asking for sounds just like material ID (so you'd use [getFaceMatID](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/MAXScript-Help/files/GUID-58D1F8B6-0012-4727-AA29-B2C79EA46E16.htm) for that). If you need to store/retrieve more info, there's also [simpleFaceManager](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/14/ENU/MAXScript%20Help%202012/files/GUID-502104A4-2A6E-4FC9-A46E-CAFEB55CD03-672.htm). Depending on how you'll be using the text file output, you can either directly write to a fileStream or use something more advanced such as XmlDocument.

Comment: Thanks for that. I knew I could use material id's but they weren't exported with obj or fbx files. I didn't want to make my own maxscript exporter but will look into doing exactly that. Something new to learn and it could be useful for the future. Will look at simpleFaceManager as well although the link doesn't work properly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, should be okay now (just switched from https to http so that it won't ask you to add a security exception). That said, if all you need is a material ID, that should work out of the box with both fbx and obj. If you export a mesh with multiple materials assigned (and all the materials have unique names), when you import it back, the material IDs are still there.